# jquery apprise in conjunction with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery's apprise plugin in conjunction with the autocomplete function. It's working correctly except that the drop down list that is displayed isn't displaying correctly. I thought that it was because of the z-index property in the css. But, I changed it accordingly and it didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to make it so that the drop down list will appear inside of the apprise box?

Thanks,

Lance

```
 $(".link").click(function(){
        apprise("<h1 class='notorious'>Link to what?</h1><div class='team_box' style='background-color:#ffffff;height:165px;'><div style='border-right:solid 1px #e4e4e4;color:#090127;width:200px;float:left;'><input type='radio' id='user' name='user'/> User <br /><input type='radio' id='current_team' name='current_team'/> Current Season Team <br /><input type='radio' id='past_team' name='past_team'/> Past Season Team <br /><input type='radio' id='season' name='season'/> Season <br /><input type='radio' id='current_player' name='current_player'/> Current Season Player <br /><input type='radio' id='past_player' name='past_player'/> Past Season Player <br /><input type='radio' id='all_star' name='all_star'/> All Star Game <br /><input type='radio' id='series' name='series'/> Series <br /></div><div id='belinda' style='float:left;margin-left:15px;'><input type='text' id='shadow' class='bar' style='display:none;'/></div></div>");

        jQuery('input[name=current_team]:radio').click(function(){
            $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');

            var data = ["Baltimore Orioles", "New York Yankees", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Tampa Bay Rays", "Boston Red Sox", "Kansas City Royals", "Chicago White Sox", "Cleveland Indians", "Detroit Tigers", "Minnesota Twins", "Texas Rangers", "Seattle Mariners", "Oakland Athletics", "Los Angeles Angels", "Philadelphia Phillies", "Atlanta Braves", "New York Mets", "Washington Nationals", "Miami Marlins", "Cincinatti Reds", "Pittsburgh Pirates", "Chicago Cubs", "St. Louis Cardinals", "Houston Astros", "Milwaukee Brewers", "Los Angeles Dodgers", "Colorado Rockies", "Arizona Diamondbacks", "San Francisco Giants", "San Diego Padres"];

            $("#shadow").autocomplete({ 
                source: data
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's always best to include a code sample to work with. Most prefer working through http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Okay. You can find the example on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/M83sF/

Answer (score 0):

The z-index is the problem. A value of 10000000000 should work.